# jquery simplePagination doesnt update on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I have implemented php function which fetches results and displays them using pagination. Also, I have tried to set on click listener in Jquery to remove active class from the previously selected page and add it to the new one.

However, it correctly switches to a different page but it does not change active class. I am using simplePagination.js

```
if (isset($_GET["list"])) { 

        $page  = $_GET["list"];

    } else { 

        $page=1; 
    } 

    $limit = 10;
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sender_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

        echo "error";   

    } else {

        echo '<br /><table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Message</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo '<tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <td>View Message</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date_time'].'</td>
                </tr>';
        }

        echo '</tbody>    
            </table>';

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(message_id) FROM inbox";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

        $total_records = $row[0];
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
        $paginationLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {  
                 $paginationLink .= "<li><a href='?page=inbox_sent&list=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
        };
        echo $paginationLink . "</ul></nav>";

    }
```

And in my Javascript file I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.pagination').pagination({
                items: 50,
                itemsOnPage: 10,
                cssStyle: 'light-theme',
                hrefTextPrefix: '?page=inbox_sent&list='
            });

        $( ".navlink" ).click(function() {
            $(".navlink").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

All results are displayed correctly, but active class of pagination always stays the same.

Comment: if the '.navlink' is beeing updated/added via pagination, then the problem is, that the event-listener `$( ".navlink" ).click(..` won't be set afterwards.

Comment: so if the nav stays were it is, there should be no need for the manual `removeClass...`.

Comment: Do you have class navigation on the rendered page? On your given source I do not see such class set.

Comment: I think the main problem is how you do the pagination. As it looks (from the fragmented code) you actually _reload_ the page, which you shouldn't. This plugin is made to work with ajax-calls.

Comment: Whenever I press on one of the pagination links, it looks like it changes class but then it reloads and comes back to first page being active whlite displaying data from list=2

Comment: As I said in my last previous comment.